# Does resubmitting a modified site map affect current ranking?

Tags: seo, xml-sitemap

I have a old sitemap dated 2012 that I submitted  in Google Webmaster Tools. I want to resubmit a modified sitemap, but I am worried that my current ranking might suffer.

Does anyone have a way that I can resubmit and make sure my site's current rankings don't drop?

Comment: See also: [The Sitemap Paradox](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox) -- sitemaps have very little to do with ranking.

Comment: bb ching: If you have additional questions, please ask them on this site using the "ask question" link, I am not planning to respond to you via email.

Answer (score 1):

(Re)submitting a sitemap does not affect rankings. All the sitemap does is tell search engines where to find your content. So changing your sitemap's contents will not cause a rankings drop. (Many sitemaps are dynamic and change daily if not hourly or minute-to-minute).

All you need to do is update your sitemap. No need to re-submit it or anything. It is automatically recrawled periodically by the search engines.

Comment: Do i delete the current sitemap and replaced it with the updated one?

Comment: @bbching Yes. Update or replace the sitemap that exists. You do not actually have to re-submit any sitemap. Google and Bing will keep checking your sitemap for updates.

Comment: If your new sitemap has a new URL, then you will have to resubmit it.  Generally you would just replace your old sitemap and re-use the same URL.